# Why copy ctor implementation is non-throwing in this example?

Tags: c++, c++11

See [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom):

```
// copy-constructor
dumb_array(const dumb_array& other)
    : mSize(other.mSize),
      mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize] : 0),
{
    // note that this is non-throwing, because of the data
    // types being used; more attention to detail with regards
    // to exceptions must be given in a more general case, however
    std::copy(other.mArray, other.mArray + mSize, mArray);
}
```

Why Copy CTOR is considered non-throwing? What if `new int[mSize]` will throw `std::bad_alloc` as it is new without `(nothrow)` argument. Also [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and throw?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It *isn't*, for the reason you give (that `new` may throw).

The comment refers only to the `std::copy`. Assigning `int`s is never going to throw anything. Good thing, too, because that would leak `mArray`. That's probably why the comment is there.

Comment: I raised a question to understand what that answer says, and now I need to raise another question to understand what you guys say. :) Please explain in details.

Comment: @Narek: What more explanation do you need? You asked why the copy-ctor is considered non-throwing. It isn't. That's it!

Comment: Then how you understand the comment here: `// note that this is non-throwing, because of the data ....`? Maybe I misunderstood it and this is where my confusion comes from?

Comment: @Narek: I addressed that in my answer. The comment relates to the `std::copy` call, not to the entire copy-constructor. Note its position inside the constructor's body.